# Cannot change width of "Dash to Panel" vertical view

Tags: dash-to-dock

I have installed ["Dash To Panel"](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/) add-on to Ubuntu.
That is because I was not satisfied with the original Ubuntu dock, which does not allow to ungroup similar apps windows.
I placed Dash To Panel on the left side of the window.
Now I cannot change its width..
I looked into the settings, maybe I am missing something...
[image]

Comment: in my case I have a large screen and I want the panel width to be wider so I can see more of the window title, just like you can do in windows. It seems crazy you can't adjust this most fundamental of settings when there is so many other minor visual things that can be tweaked

Comment: @Andy I am not sure I understand your point... If you know how to increase panel width, please share your advice.. Otherwise I am confused with your comment..

Answer (score 0):

You choose to use traditional taskbar buttons with text. Why, then, you would you want a vertical layout to be smaller? That would prevent the text to be displayed.

- To use the panel in a vertical layout, revert to the default icon-only buttons. Then you will have more flexibility in changing the width.
- You could consider autohiding the taskbar, so that it pops over the existing window with legible labels each time you need to access it.
- Else, you may need to file an issue to the developer of the Gnome Extension as to support a smaller display when using taskbar buttons with text.

Comment: Icons do not provide names of the windows of similar app (e. g. numerous Google chrome windows grouped in 5 groups). It is enough for me to see first 3-4 letters of the name to understand it's full name. The dock should be shortened because I need more space to the right to open 2 windows simultaneously.

Comment: I updated my answer with your three, as far as I am aware, current options.

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately, none of those three helps.. I also have filed similar issue to the github of the extension, no response from the developer yet.. I am wondering maybe there is some mysterious setting I don't know about..

Comment: I see no other option than those I gave, apart from a fourth one, which is delving into the source code of the extension yourself.